# WPF button with two sides

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What I'm trying to do is create a button that would have two labels (one on right and one on left side.

Right side label (and whole right side) must be in different color that left side ([you can see a sample of button here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWbPR.jpg)).

I tried creating new custom control with grid, dock panel etc... but nothing looked like i wanted. So im asking you.

How to create a button like this?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to put a `StackPanel` in your button's content property. In this Stackpanel you can put 2 `TextBlock`. If you want to put custom colors for each of you sides, you might want to englobe your `TextBlock` in `Border` block. The `Border` blocks has background properties.

An example of that would be:

```
    <Button Height="20" Width="50">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Background="Yellow">
                <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="Test2"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

You can then play with the StackPanel's sizes, border's color, textblock's text and whatever other property you might want to change.

Comment: This one seems to be a correct answer. I was surprised you can set controls inside button content even I have done few WPF projects myself.

Comment: That's the reason the property is named "Content" and not only "Text".  It can only contain one block though so that's why you need to put a StackPanel that contains the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use a Grid as button's content and use borders for colors.

```
 <Button x:Name="MyButton" Padding="10px"
            Width="200" Height="75" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="White">
                    <TextBlock Text="Some Text"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="red">
                    <TextBlock Text="text2"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>

            </Grid>
        </Button>
```

[image: XAML preview]